# refresh on commit view with group by MAX

Tags: oracle

I am attempting to create a materialised view on a table without a where clause.  However the `"REFRESH ON COMMIT"` is being refused by oracle.

Is there a way to structure this so that its updatable?
`created` is a date.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_SNR_LATEST REFRESH ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT * FROM T_SNR snr
WHERE (snr.created, snr.m_id, snr.snor, snr.ai)
IN (SELECT MAX(created), m_id, snor, ai 
FROM t_snr s2 GROUP BY s2.M_ID, s2.snor, s2.AI);
```

Comment: Check this one [Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Aggregates](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, check [General Restrictions on Fast Refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-505C24CF-5D56-4820-88AA-2221410950E7)

> The defining query of the materialized view is restricted as follows:
>
> - The materialized view must not contain references to non-repeating expressions like SYSDATE and ROWNUM.
> - The materialized view must not contain references to RAW or LONG RAW data types.
> - **It cannot contain a SELECT list subquery.**
> - It cannot contain analytic functions (for example, RANK) in the SELECT clause.
> - It cannot reference a table on which an XMLIndex index is defined.
> - It cannot contain a MODEL clause.
> - It cannot contain a HAVING clause with a subquery.
> - It cannot contain nested queries that have ANY, ALL, or NOT EXISTS.
> - It cannot contain a [START WITH …] CONNECT BY clause.
> - It cannot contain multiple detail tables at different sites.
> - ON COMMIT materialized views cannot have remote detail tables.
> - Nested materialized views must have a join or aggregate.
> - Materialized join views and materialized aggregate views with a GROUP BY clause cannot select from an index-organized table.

Comment: yip, I think you are correct. I will wait a bit to see if there are other responses, or methods of restructuring the query before accepting that it's not possible.